# Issue with pulling a specific taxonomy (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

Ok I have created a custom post type and a custom taxonomy for that custom post type. The post type is called "solutions" and the taxonomy is called "solution_categories".

I have tried multiple examples

```
<?php get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'solution_categories', '<li class="jobs_item">', '', '</li>' ) ?>

$terms = get_term_by('solution_categories');
```

I have tried get_terms(); aswell to no avail. I have been all over stack overflow aswell.

Comment: Where are you using this, what exactly are you trying to achieve. It is totally unclear what your exact question is

Comment: @PieterGoosen My question is in my title. Regardless of where, I am trying to pull a custom taxonomy

Comment: What do you mean by "pull a custom taxonomy"? What do you want to get? The actual taxonomy? The posts within that taxonomy? That's not clear

Comment: I want to pull the actuall taxonomy

Comment: That does not make no sense at all. Also, question descriptions should be in your post body, not title.

Comment: Stop replying with *pull the taxonomy*. You cannot pull a taxonomy. What do you need to do with the taxonomy or its terms

Comment: One other issue I forget, it **does** matter where you are using that code as `$post` can be any value depending on page. Inside the loop and outside the loop, this differ big time and will give unexpected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified [by the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms), the proper format for `get_terms()` is:

```
get_terms( $taxonomies, $args );
```

In your case, you would use:

```
get_terms( 'solution_categories' );
```

Keep in mind, this doesn't `echo` or display the terms, it just retrieves them.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. I retrieved the terms, but it returns a bool(false). does this mean I created my taxonomy incorrectly?

Comment: That means that there are no terms within the `'solution_categories'` taxonomy.

Comment: I added 4 terms inside my taxonomy just as a test